# Keeping user data after upgrating a Windows Phone application

Tags: windows-phone

I have a Windows Phone application which needs to save some user data/settings in a xml file BUT when I upgrade and install a new version of this application, the data are destroyed and reset.

How can I preserve data/settings in a xml format when upgrading my application (for one version to a newer)?

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/gg442301(v=vs.105).aspx),

**Updating apps and isolated storage**

When you update your app, any data in the isolated storage is preserved. However, data in the isolated storage is deleted if the user uninstalls and then reinstalls your app. For more information, see Data for Windows Phone 8.

Are you rebuilding the project every time before debugging? That will remove and install the app freshly. Try publishing the app on store in beta and update it. That should preserve app data.